# Where can i find the Class variable in GameClosure

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, gameclosure

gameclosure uses the class structure for code modulation

example code 1:

```
exports = Class(GC.Application, function() {
  //Code here
});
```

I was trying to look for the code inside the Class varible,
I found a Class varible declartion in `jsio/packages/base.js`

```
exports.Class = function(name, parent, proto) {
    return exports.__class__(
        function() { 
          return this.init && this.init.apply(this, arguments); 
        }, 
        name, parent, proto);
}
```

but, this function is not syntactically the same as to be used by the example code mentioned above.
so, my question is where is the class varibale located.
and what is the use for the jsio/packages/base.js class variable?
also, how can i call the super class methods from the extended class?

Comment: What do you mean by "*this function is not syntactically the same as to be used by the example code*"?

Comment: @Bergi the exports.class function is getting the parent class as the second parameter while in the example the base class is passed in the first parameter.

Comment: It might well be just overloaded, and `name` is optional. Check what `__class__` does, I'm pretty sure if shifts the arguments if `name` is not a string.

Comment: @Bergi yes, you are right, the __class__  function is shifting the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you have all ready found the answer,incase you havent found the answer to the second question. this is how you can call a super class method from the base class.

```
var Vehicle = Class(function () {
    this.init = function (wheels) {
        this.wheels = wheels;
    };
});

var Truck = Class(Vehicle, function (supr) {

    this.init = function (hp, wheels) {
        supr(this, "init", [wheels]);
        this.horsepower = hp;
    };

    this.printInfo = function () {
        $('#result').html('I am a truck and I have ' + this.wheels +
                ' wheels and ' + this.horsepower + ' hp.');
    };
});

var t = new Truck(350, 4);
t.printInfo();
```